# image downloaded using universal image loader have same fixed size

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

i m using UIL to download and show images in imageview

firstly i didn't specify the

```
memoryCacheExtraOptions(int, int) option
```

for loader configuration and i was using it to show a thumbnail for my images downloaded from server and the result was as i want

but now i want to show each image in different activity and now i want to fit the entire imageview size that i specified

so i tried to add this option

```
 memoryCacheExtraOptions(myimageviewwidth, myimageviewheight)
```

but the result was same and the the image in the details activity is shown smaller than image in thumbnail

this is my configuration

```
 configuration=new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .build();
```

and this is my image view

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/p_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:src="@drawable/d" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

those are to image of the result that i got

[image: thumbnail]

[image: details]

any help?

Comment: try this :ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
  .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
  .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
  .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
  .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
  .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
  .build();
  // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
  ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

Comment: do u mean to define another configuration in my project are use this instead of mine?

Comment: use this instead of your old configuration

Comment: same result and it's obvious because ur config is as same is mine just u used disccachefilenamegenerator which is decrepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem by doing no thing with image loader

just i added those two line to the image view XML

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```